# JQuery Org Chart with Jquery library [dependency] 3.1.0 is working but not working with 1.11.1 version

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, orgchart

I am using query org chart to showing organisation level chart. It is working fine when I am using query version **jquery-3.1.0.min** but when I am using query version **jquery-1.11.1.min** , its not working I am getting below error when loading the page.

[image]

link to plugin is : https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart

Initialization to the chart is

```
$('#chart-container').orgchart({
              'data' : createStructure(), /*js function to get json structure */
              'ajaxURL': ajaxURLs,
              'nodeContent': 'title',
              'nodeId': 'id',
              'exportButton': true,
              'exportFilename': 'MyOrgChart'
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart will work with **jquery-3.1.0.min** . it does not support **jquery-1.11.1.min**

Just use **jquery-3.1.0.min** as jquery version , it will work .

Thanks